# How to make multiple targets by the same rule using target-dependent compilers?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Suppose that I would like to verify the compatibility of `hello.c` with multiple compilers. How to do it using a Makefile?

Here is a Makefile I write for this purpose.

```
# Makefile, version 1. 
# It tests hello.c using multiple compilers. 

TEST = test_gcc test_clang
.PHONY: $(TEST) all

all: $(TEST)

test_gcc: CC = gcc
test_clang: CC = clang

$(TEST): hello 
    ./hello
    rm -f hello

hello: hello.c
    $(CC) hello.c -o hello
```

If I run `make test_gcc` or `test_clang`, everything works. However, `make all` leads to the following.

```
./hello
Hello, world!
rm -f hello
touch hello.c
./hello
make : ./hello : command not found
make: *** [Makefile:10 : test_clang] Error 127
```

So `hello` is not remade for `test_clang`. This seems to a Makfile beginner like me.

**Question**: In my Makefile, `test_clang` depends on `hello`, which has been removed when `test_gcc` is finished. So why doesn't `make` generate it again before running `./hello` ?

**My Attempts:**

To solve the problem, I tried the following modification, which touches `hello.c` after making `test_gcc` or `test_clang`. It still does not work, the problem being the same.

```
# Makefile, version 2. 
# It tests hello.c using multiple compilers. 

TEST = test_gcc test_clang
.PHONY: $(TEST) all

all: $(TEST)

test_gcc: CC = gcc
test_clang: CC = clang

$(TEST): hello hello.c
    ./hello
    rm -f hello
    touch hello.c

hello: hello.c
    $(CC) hello.c -o hello
```

Following the advice of @HolyBlackCat, I tried also the following.

```
# Makefile, version 3.
# It tests hello.c using multiple compilers.

TEST = test_gcc test_clang
.PHONY: $(TEST) all

all: $(TEST)

test_gcc: CC = gcc
test_clang: CC = clang

$(TEST): hello_$(CC)
    ./hello_$(CC)
    rm -f hello_$(CC)

hello_$(CC): hello.c
    $(CC) hello.c -o hello_$(CC)
```

The output of `make all` is

```
gcc hello.c -o hello_gcc
./hello_gcc
Hello, world!
rm -f hello_gcc
./hello_clang
make : ./hello_clang : commande not found
make: *** [Makefile:13 : test_clang] Error 127
```

This is even stranger --- `hello_clang` is never made even though it is required (only) by `test_clang`.

For your convenience, here is the standard `hello.c` I used for the test.

```
/* hello.c */

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions. It will also be appreciated if you comment on my Makefiles in general, not necessarily regarding the question I raised. I am really a beginner.

Comment: I believe Make never builds a target more than once per invocation. You might need to have several targets in place of `hello`, one per compiler.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried but did not manage to make it work. See the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for target-specific variables: it's quite clear that target-specific variables take effect *only* in recipes.  You cannot use them in prerequisites, or of course when defining targets.

It's probably simpler to do this without target-specific variables and just use pattern rules instead:

```
TEST = test_gcc test_clang
.PHONY: all

all: $(TEST)

test_%: hello_%
        ./$<

hello_%: hello.c
        $* $< -o $@
```

(I don't know why you're removing the binary immediately after you test it, in this version, so I removed that).

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. However, I have not managed to make your Makefile work on my side. Here is what I got by `make all`: `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`

Comment: As for removing the binary: as I mentioned, my purpose is to verify the compatibility of my code with various compilers instead of producing the binary. I guess this may not be a quite uncommon practice in the development of a piece of portable software. Thank you.

Comment: The result for `make test_gcc` is similar, which seems quite strange, because there is obviously a rule for making `test_gcc`.

Comment: Sorry you have to remove `$(TEST)` from the `.PHONY` target.  Phony targets cannot be built using pattern rules (that's one of the ways that they're special).  I updated my example.  If you really just want to run tests then remove the program I'm not sure there's even any need for two rules.  You could just make a single test rule.